# Receive server messages as a client in random time

Tags: python, server, client

I'm trying to write a simple messenger in python so I have to receive messages from server when another client sends it there. I use socket, so is there an easy way to receive these random messages, or do I have to write some "while True" construction in my client?

Comment: You can use requests as a client and flask as a server-side, simpler and faster way in comparison to socket module where you have to define your own app protocol.

Comment: Please, show us the code you have written so far. This link may help to ask proper questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two modes: blocking and non-blocking.

### Blocking

Your code schematically looks like this:

```
while not stop:
    message = read_message_from_socket(socket)
    # do something with message
```

`stop` is a variable that is used to signal client that it should stop processing messages from the server.

And `read_message_from_socket` uses `recv` method to read the data from the server.

In this case the call to `recv` is blocking which means that it does not return until server sends some data.

Note that this is very simplified because it may happen that `recv` will return only part of the data you are expecting, so there will be probably a loop inside `read_message_from_socket` to wait till the whole message is read (it may be based on the known size of the message or it may rely on the symbol like end of line).

### Non Blocking

In this case the code of the client schematically looks like this:

```
sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

while not stop:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    for key, mask in events:
        service_connection(key, mask)

        if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
           socket = key.fileobj
           message = read_actual_message_from_socket(socket)
           # process the message
```

In this case the call to `select` will block until new data arrives from the server. And it is guaranteed that `read_actual_message_from_socket` will read some data (the same as in the previous case it may get only some portion of data so this requires additional handling).

More introductory information on this is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto) and some examples are [here](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#handling-multiple-connections).

Comment: Thank you! Information about blocking and non blocking sockets was very helpful, I've created a non blocking socket and every second I recvfrom to check if there's a message. Not the best way, maybe, but it works fine :D